# Pandas sort_values error after convert set_axis inplace=True to copy=False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to programing. I am using Conda python3.9 with Pandas 1.5.2. running jupyter notebook for some data handling. I have two lines

buffer_status.set_axis(['ProjectID','UpdatedAt','ProjectName'],axis='columns', inplace=True)
buffer_status.sort_values(by='ProjectID', ascending=False, inplace=True)

It gives me warning set_axis 'inplace' keyword is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use `obj = obj.set_axis(..., copy=False)` instead.

But it works. So I follow their advices and replace inplace

```
buffer_status.set_axis(['ProjectID','UpdatedAt','ProjectName'],axis='columns', copy=False)
buffer_status.sort_values(by='ProjectID', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

And it gives error with below (just copying their highlights)

```
-> 35 buffer_status.sort_values(by='ProjectID', ascending=False, inplace=True)
-> 6909     k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
-> 1850     raise KeyError(key)
   1852 # Check for duplicates
   1853 if values.ndim > 1:
```

Any idea why set_axis copy=False does not work with sort_values?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't completely followed their advice, they mention obj = obj.DoSomething():

so it should be:

```
buffer_status = buffer_status.set_axis(['ProjectID','UpdatedAt','ProjectName'],axis='columns', copy=False)
```

this way the variable `buffer_status` is actually changed, since you only removed inplace, the variable is not modified "in its place", so you have to assign the changes somewhere, either a new variable, or the same which is then updated.

So your set_axis code is currently executed, but the result is not stored, therefore the buffer_status hast no column ProjectID, which is why you get a KeyError (the key ProjectID is not in the columns).

Comment: Ar.. you are correct. Thanks. Just thought it is a simple replacement and missed the mutation of the object. Thanks